# Can't install Rasa on Ubuntu 18.04 + Python 3.7.5?

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-18.04, rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-x

I have succeed to install Rasa NLU on my Win 10 with python 3.7 but couldn't do this on Ubuntu 18.04.
Please help.

Here is the error I get:

```
pip3 install rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple
```

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   tensorflow~=1.15.0 (from rasa~=1.5.1->rasa-x) (from versions:
>   1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1) No matching distribution found for tensorflow~=1.15.0 (from rasa~=1.5.1->rasa-x)

Please advise what is the difference to my Win10 machine?
Please advise how can I install it.

Answer (score 2):

**I had followed these following steps and it's working fine for me for ubuntu 18.04 + Python3**

Firstly create directory name of your choice and get inside of it

```
mkdir rasaprojects #directory name of your choice in place of rasaprojects

cd rasaprojects   #get inside that directory
```

Now create virtual environment of python3

```
virtualenv rasaenv -p python3 #write your environment name instead of rasaenv
```

Now activate the environment

```
source rasaenv/bin/activate
```

Now you are good to go with rasa installation

```
pip3 install rasa
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating your pip version should solve the issue. I believe TensorFlow and your current pip version don't go well together.

Do this:

1. Download pip installer python script from [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).
2. Run it using `python get-pip.py`

Another thing is that TensorFlow was not supported by python3.7 untill recently. So if the first solution doesn't work you can try downgrading python to python3.6

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade `pip` before instaling `rasa`.

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```